# My program never ends in while loop

Tags: python-3.x, while-loop

So I am trying to make my code take a person's desired character and make a pyramid with a desired base. But when I execute the program, the output never ends and no characters ever output.

This is the following code:

```
pyramid = str()
charnum = int(1)
num2 = 0
num3 = 0
char = input("Input character to make pyramid: ")
numb = input("Input what the base number has to be: ")
if int(numb) % 2 != 0:
    numb2 = int(numb)
    numb2 = (int(numb2) - 1) / 2

while int(numb2) != -1:
    print(pyramid)
    pyramid = ("")
    numb3 = int(numb2)
    numb2 = int(numb2) - 1
    charnum2 = int(charnum)
    charnum = int(charnum) + 2

while int(numb3) != 0:
    pyramid += " "
    numb3 = int(numb3) - 1

while int(charnum2) != 0:
    pyramid += char
    charnum2 = int(charnum2) - 1
```

Any help would be much apreciated

Comment: There is no need for most of the `int()` calls. To assign a zero, just use `num2 = 0`. Python is dynamically typed, *names* have no type, you just assign values.

Comment: Ok, thank you, I will edit it now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in your third while loop, you are checking the value of charnum2, but not modifying it ever, you only modify charnum. Since the value of charnum2 never changes if it was no 0 to begin with the loop will run forever.

**Edit:** after looking through your code some more, it looks like you now have all the parts there, just the indentation of your Questions code is off. If your actual source is working at this point then you can ignore this but, it looks like you should indent some of you while loops so everything looks like:

```
pyramid = str()
charnum = int(1)
num2 = 0
num3 = 0
char = input("Input character to make pyramid: ")
numb = input("Input what the base number has to be: ")
if int(numb) % 2 != 0:
    numb2 = int(numb)
    numb2 = (int(numb2) - 1) / 2

    while int(numb2) != -1:
        print(pyramid)
        pyramid = ("")
        numb3 = int(numb2)
        numb2 = int(numb2) - 1
        charnum2 = int(charnum)
        charnum = int(charnum) + 2

        while int(numb3) != 0:
            pyramid += " "
            numb3 = int(numb3) - 1

        while int(charnum2) != 0:
            pyramid += char
            charnum2 = int(charnum2) - 1
```

This way the first while loop is run once for each line of the pyramid, and the following two add the correct characters in the pyramid.

Comment: Ok now it has given me an output but without the added character

Comment: if what you have posted is all the code you have, there is nothing that actually prints anything out after the first if statement.

Comment: It still seems to output anything even after placing it in the loop

Comment: also in the first while loop you are comparing against num2 but never set num2 to anything other than 0 at the beginning so that loop only ever runs once.

Comment: @Stefan please see my edit if you are still having issues

Comment: This is a lot of help I will edit accordingly, thank you